# Is CakePHP really secured for large websites?

Tags: security, cakephp-2.0

I'm planning of developing a large website, Which I need to take some security measures, I'm right now using CakePHP 2.0.1.

what are the plugins or components that I need to use, so that my website doesn't gets hacked.

I found a loop hole in CakePHP, that I have a page to change password, it has only 2 fields, change password & repeat password, but when I tried adding the below in change password through firebug, It updated the email field in database.

```
<input type="text" id="UserEmail" value="admin123" maxlength="100" class="input-xlarge span6" name="data[User][email]">
```

How can I get rid of these types of hacks ?

Comment: The question in the title is subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CakePHP http://www.hotscripts.com/ uses cakephp and they are big.

Although size should not make a difference with security. It may be that you might be attacked more if you are larger. But you should always be secure regardless of size.